# Help with Artificer/Wizard

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, wizard, artificer

I'm having isues understanding the item creation process and usage for an Artificer with a Wizard dip. As far I understand the process, a straight Artificer needs to make a Use Magic Device check to create and use any arcane device.

What about the Artificer/Wizard? Does he needs to make a UMD check for creating a device with an arcane spell?

Answer (score 1):

A straight Artificer has to make UMD checks to cover the spells needed to craft an item, whether those spells are Arcane or Divine.

An Artificer/Wizard would still have to make a UMD check (DC 20 + minimum caster level of spell) for all spells he couldn't himself cast.

Which means a one level dip into wizard would allow you to forgo the check on all the 1st level spells and cantrips in your spell book only... which quickly become trivial UMD checks.

It is for this reason and others that Artificers rarely dip, as each level in artificer grows less efficient (comparatively) for each level of anything else you take.

Comment: Artificers like to get to level 14 before considering anything else - typically a prestige class like Effigy Master, Master Alchemist, Battlesmith, etc.

Comment: True... but then again, going straight Artificer 20 isn't a bad option for those generalists.

Comment: Oh, I am not in disagreement. Just supporting your comment that Artificers rarely dip.